# Using a `<textarea>` to protect against scripts

Tags: php, security, textarea, xss

Hmm.  Instead of "defanging" input or using some kind of regex to remove tags, how safe is it to dump user stuff into a `<textarea>`?

For example, say there's a PHP page that does the following:

```
echo '<textarea>';
echo $_GET['whuh_you_say'] ;
echo '</textarea>';
```

Normally this is vulnerable to xss attacks, but in the `textarea`, all script tags will just show up as `<script>` and they won't be executed.

Is this unsafe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
</textarea>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("this safe...");
    /* load malicious c0dez! */
  </script>
<textarea>
```

Comment: if you were always going to use textarea...you could develop a simple regex pattern to ONLY remove textarea etc from the string to prevent the above attack...and let the textarea itself take care of the rest

Comment: +1 beat me to it - @davidsleeps - while that may be true, the *best* way to deal with this is whitelisting only the tags you need, and making sure you are sanitizing any output generated by a user's input

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily be simple. What if I put
`</text</textarea>area>`. It still needs to be thought through.

Comment: You should be using htmlspecialshars() anyway, even if you're putting it inside a <textarea>

Comment: @Svish — no. `<textarea>` elements do not contain CDATA.

Answer (score 2):

If your users aren't supposed to be using any HTML tags whatsoever (which if you're proposing this textarea solution, that's the case), just run it through `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` and be done with it. Guaranteed safety.

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags(string);`

Is wonderful! Honest!

Comment: It was broken in some versions of PHP, though. http://www.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/securityfocus/bugtraq/2004-07/0149.html

Comment: Don't use it on text - you'll get invalid entities. Use htmlspecialchars() instead (as a bonus, it won't destroy innocent text like "1<2")

Answer (score 0):

This talks about an XSS hole found in textarea's in google documents (I think the post is a little old - so google have probably secured it by now), but it deomstrates how textareas can be used as an attack vector.

[ha.ckers.org discussing google docs textarea exploit](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070617/another-google-xss-in-google-documents/)

Answer (score -2):

Good enough for the basics:

```
sanitized = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $_GET['whuh_you_say']);
sanitized = str_replace(">", "&gt;", sanitized);
```

Comment: Or you could just use htmlentities().